# javascript. Почему не работает простейший таймер?

Tags: javascript, html, функции

Почему этот код не работает? 
Я пытаюсь сделать простой таймер.
Я хочу чтобы после нажатия на кнопку в HTML, срабатывала функция JavaScript, которой, через ее переменные передается количество секунд и тег дива, в котором она будет печатать таймер. Функция должна разделить число первой переменной на 60 (получив минуты и секунды в остатке), написать на странице, отнять от исходного числа 1 и повторять это с задержкй в одну секунду до тех пор, пока значение переменной не будет = 0.

Я тестировал этот вариант и до и после написания условия, останавливающего функцию, но она не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

```html
<script>
function timer(tag,txt){ 

document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML+=txt/60 + '<br>'; 
txt = txt - 1;

setTimeout(timer,1000);

}
</script> 

<div id="str"></div> 

<input type="button" onclick="timer('str',800)" value="Нажми меня" />
```

Comment: addText  - нет такой функии.

Comment: @user190134  Сори, очепятка, поменял название функции уже после публикации, во время теста все названия совпадали.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { timer(tag, txt); }, 1000);`

Comment: через консольку отлавливай ошибки.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо огромное, работает!

Comment: @user190134 Еще не умею)

Comment: Привет.
Ты хотел получить что-то вроде этого?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/QUZQ5.jpg

Comment: В браузере когда запускаешь скрипт, жми F12 и выбирай консоль( для хрома) , или Ctrl+shift+k(Для мозилы), и тебе будут показывать ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var x='str';
            var time=800;
            function timer(){ 

                document.getElementById(x).innerHTML+=time/60 + '<br>'; 
                time = time - 5;

                if (time>0) {setTimeout("timer()",100);} else {alert("Computed");} 

            }
        </script> 

        <div id="str"></div> 

        <input type="button" onclick="timer()" value="Нажми меня" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень интересный вариант! У меня тоже в конце концов получилось правда немножко иаче, но у такой задачи может быть множество вариантов решения.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему этот код не работает?

Ты вызываешь:

```
setTimeout(timer,1000);
```

Но если ты хочешь передать асинхронно параметры - надо вызывать так както:

```
setTimeout(function(){timer(tag,txt);},1000);
```

Можно юзать тут setInterval:

```js
var interval, txt;
function timer(tag, txt){ 
  document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML+=txt/60 + '<br>'; 
};
```

```html
<div id="str"></div> 
<input type="button" onclick="txt = 800;interval = setInterval(function(){timer('str', txt--);}, 1000)" value="Нажми меня" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(interval)" value="Останови меня" />
```

Не вставлять рекурсию(пусть асинхронную) там где она не требуется - добро.

Comment: Спасибо большое, интересный вариант! Правда в моем случае мне необходимо чтобы таймер сам останавливался. А почему рекурсия не желательна? 

P.S.
Я заметил странную вещь - задержка тормозит вместе с браузером. Интересно, есть ли более точные варианты...

Comment: Незачто. Хуже читаема, хуже управляема. А по поводу того - чтобы таймер сам останавливался: clearTimeout и clearInterval функции есть.

Comment: функция `setTimeout` после времени таймаута принимает параметры, которые будут переданы в callback

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
  function timer(tag, txt) {
    document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML += txt / 60 + '<br>';
    txt = txt - 1;
    setTimeout(timer, 1000, tag, txt);
  }
</script>

<div id="str"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="timer('str',800)" value="Нажми меня" />
```