# Как выполнять скрипт каждую секунду с помощью ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Скрипт работает только один раз. Нужно чтобы работал постоянно, то есть повторялся каждую секунду. Как такое можно реализовать с помощью ajax?

Comment: а почему бы не использовать для этого таймер?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [javascript. Почему не работает простейший таймер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540327/javascript-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80)

Answer (score 2):

функция `setInterval`

пример:

```
setInterval(function() {
   //все что будет внутри - будет выполняться постоянно
}, 1000)
```